# How to import a big project to xilinx SDK and generate .elf?

Tags: sdk, embedded, xilinx, zynq

I'm very new to zedboard.

I have a big project, which has several hierarchical makefiles. I want to import the project into xilinx SDK, build it, and generate the elf file, and load it to Zedboard zynq 7000 xc7z020clg484. Or, load the project into the ARM memory, build it, and execute it.

I tried import->existing project, but it seems doesn't work. I still can't build it.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you developed your existing project in Xilinx SDK, you won't be able to import it directly into a Xilinx SDK workspace.  First, create a fresh workspace and then create a Xilinx SDK Makefile project from your existing source code (see graphic).  You can edit the resulting makefile as you need to build your hierarchies.

[image: Existing Code]

You should also include the hardware platform project, created in Vivado, that describes the hardware the embedded software will run on (i.e. The available resources and peripherals on the Zedboard).

[Zedboard.org](http://www.zedboard.org) has a wealth of documentation, training videos, tutorials, and support forums.